# Tensorflow VGG16 SENet implementation prediction problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I need to implement a SENet (squeeze-and-excitation blocks) in key points of my CNN VGG16. Everything runs fine but when I decode the prediction, the result I get is very strange. I give it a picture of a "panda" and it tells me that it is a "cloak". And when I test with the official VGG16 I do not have the same problem. Whether with or without the SENet block.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Conv2D, Input, BatchNormalization, Reshape, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid, softmax, relu, tanh
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import vis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras import backend as K
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions,VGG16, preprocess_input
from vis.utils import utils
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
class SENET_Attn(Layer):
def __init__(self,out_dim, ratio, layer_name="SENET"):
super(SENET_Attn, self).__init__()
self.out_dim = out_dim
self.ratio = ratio
self.layer_name = layer_name
def build(self, ratio, layer_name="SENET"):
self.Global_Average_Pooling = GlobalAveragePooling2D(keepdims= True)
self.Fully_connected_1_1 = Dense(units= self.out_dim/self.ratio, name=self.layer_name+'_fully_connected1'
self.Relu = ReLU()
self.Fully_connected_2 = Dense(units=self.out_dim, name=layer_name+'_fully_connected2', activation = "tanh"
self.Sigmoid = Activation("sigmoid")
def call(self, inputs):
inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype = "float32")
squeeze = self.Global_Average_Pooling(inputs)
excitation = self.Fully_connected_1_1(squeeze)
excitation = self.Relu(excitation)
excitation = self.Fully_connected_2(excitation)
excitation = self.Sigmoid(excitation)
excitation = tf.reshape(excitation, [-1,1,1,self.out_dim])
scale = inputs * excitation
return scale
Vgg = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
# SENET-RATIO
ratio = 8
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224,224,3))
out = Vgg.layers[1](input_layer) # Block 1 of VGG16
out = Vgg.layers[2](out)
out = Vgg.layers[3](out)
#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[4](out) # Block 2 of VGG16
out = Vgg.layers[5](out)
out = Vgg.layers[6](out)
#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[7](out) # Block 3 of VGG16
out = Vgg.layers[8](out)
out = Vgg.layers[9](out)
out = Vgg.layers[10](out)
#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[11](out) # Block 4 of VGG16
out = Vgg.layers[12](out)
out = Vgg.layers[13](out)
out = Vgg.layers[14](out)
#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
out = Vgg.layers[15](out) #Block 5 of VGG16
out = Vgg.layers[16](out)
out = Vgg.layers[17](out)
out = Vgg.layers[18](out)
#out = SENET_Attn(out.shape[-1], ratio, )(out) # SENET Attention
flatten = Flatten()(out)
out = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(flatten)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
out = Dense(1000, activation='softmax')(out)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs= out)
model.compile('adam', loss ='mae', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_24"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type) Output Shape Param #
=================================================================
input_99 (InputLayer) [(None, 224, 224, 3)] 0
block1_conv1 (Conv2D) (None, 224, 224, 64) 1792
block1_conv2 (Conv2D) (None, 224, 224, 64) 36928
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 112, 112, 64) 0
block2_conv1 (Conv2D) (None, 112, 112, 128) 73856
block2_conv2 (Conv2D) (None, 112, 112, 128) 147584
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 56, 56, 128) 0
block3_conv1 (Conv2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 295168
block3_conv2 (Conv2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 590080
block3_conv3 (Conv2D) (None, 56, 56, 256) 590080
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 28, 28, 256) 0
block4_conv1 (Conv2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 1180160
block4_conv2 (Conv2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 2359808
block4_conv3 (Conv2D) (None, 28, 28, 512) 2359808
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 0
block5_conv1 (Conv2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808
block5_conv2 (Conv2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808
block5_conv3 (Conv2D) (None, 14, 14, 512) 2359808
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D) (None, 7, 7, 512) 0
flatten_24 (Flatten) (None, 25088) 0
dense_72 (Dense) (None, 4096) 102764544
dropout_14 (Dropout) (None, 4096) 0
dense_73 (Dense) (None, 4096) 16781312
dropout_15 (Dropout) (None, 4096) 0
dense_74 (Dense) (None, 1000) 4097000
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
img = load_img('Panda.jpg',target_size=(224,224))
x = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
print('The most accurate possibility is :', tf.keras.applications.vgg16.decode_predictions(model.predict(x), top=3)[0])
```

```
The most accurate possibility is : [('n03045698', 'cloak', 0.9999887), ('n01692333', 'Gila_monster', 5.1300117e-06), ('n02965783', 'car_mirror', 2.17886e-06)]
```

I imagine that is one of the layers that is missing, but in the summary of my model it is the same layers and the same parameters. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you for your help.

Comment: On which dataset are you training this network?

Comment: Im using the ImageNet dataset.

Comment: ImageNet is not a trivial dataset to use, make sure you implemented all the proper steps, specially data augmentation, I don't see any of those details in your question.

Comment: Ok, i found were does my problem come from i just remove the one i done by hand and implement the one use by the official VGG16. But my SENet is making me going further from the prediction. I will try to find a solution for this. Thank you.